# Primes in integral domains

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $\mathcal O_{\mathbb K}$ be the ring of integers in a number field $\mathbb K$. It is easy to prove that the number of (non-associated) primes in $\mathcal O_{\mathbb K}$ is infinite.
On the other hand, for any field $\mathbb F$ there is only one (non-associated) prime in the power series ring $\mathbb F[[x]] $, namely the element x. Any integral domain that I imagine the question of finitude or infinity of primes is easy.

My question is: is there any integral domain in which the question of finitude or infinitude of prime elements is open? Or, at least, very difficult to prove?

Comment: If you contacted E.G., he would know.

Comment: Are you looking for examples that are "natural" in some sense? It's not hard to encode open problems in a somewhat silly way in the primes of an integral domain. For example, consider the ring of rational numbers whose denominator is coprime to all twin primes.